# Removing Brackets from itertools combination list results

Tags: python, django, combinations, python-itertools

I have this code

```
import itertools
import random

def gen_reset_key():
    key = random.randint(100, 199)
    return key

key_combinations = list(itertools.combinations(str(gen_reset_key()), 2))

key_one = key_combinations[0]
key_two = key_combinations[1]
key_three = key_combinations[2]

print("Key one is: {}".format(key_one))
print("Key two is: {}".format(key_two))
print("Key three is: {}".format(key_three))
```

The output is:

```
Key one is: ('1', '9')
Key two is: ('1', '9')
Key three is: ('9', '9')
```

I want to remove the brackets and speech marks from the output. How can I achieve that?

so that my output would be:

```
Key one is 19
Key two is 19
Key three is 99
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish this in the following way (without using `str.join`):

```py
print('Key one is: {}{}'.format(*key_one))
print('Key two is: {}{}'.format(*key_two))
print('Key three is: {}{}'.format(*key_three))
```

This should have the added benefit of avoiding the creation of intermediate strings in the `join`.

Answer (score 1):

These are tuples. You can join the characters in the tuples with `''.join(..)`:

```
print('Key one is: {}'.format(''.join(key_one)))
print('Key two is: {}'.format(''.join(key_two)))
print('Key three is: {}'.format(''.join(key_three)))
```